# Why do Python type hints sometimes worsen IDE recommendations?

Tags: python, mypy, type-hinting, python-typing

I'm going through an exercise of adding type hints through a large codebase, but I'm sometimes seeing that less-than-optimal type hint worsens IDE recommendations:

Before, the IDE is able to figure out that y['result'] is a string:

[image]

After, it does not know:

[image]

I know I could fix this with a more specific type hint:

[image]

But in general, is there a way to know if the type hint being added is less specific that what the [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Server_Protocol) was able to infer from the code?

I've looked to add very detailed type hints to avoid this issue (e.g., subclassing TypeDict), but I am keen to avoid the effort if the LSP is able to figure things out itself.

I'm asking if there is a way to warn the user when they are adding a type hint that will worsen the LSP's understanding of the code:

We have warnings when the type hints contradict the code:

[image]

I'm looking for some warning for when the type hint is worse than no type hint at all.

[image]

You can see here that the LSP was easily able to infer a pretty detailed return type.

[image]

Which would have been lost if the user added a "bad" type hint.

[image]

But I take the overall feedback. Maybe this is an ask to the [Pylance](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/announcing-pylance-fast-feature-rich-language-support-for-python-in-visual-studio-code/) project more than a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: I'm not sure langserver feature requests are a good fit for Stack Overflow. Better to file a ticket for the language server you're using. (Also, if you're using VS Code, my understanding is that the usual langserver is pyright-langserver or the non-OSS pylance, not pylsp-mypy -- given the question's tagging, did you _explicitly_ configure the latter?)

Comment: I'm also not sure it's reliably possible to determine that a hint is "worse". How do we know it's really "worse" and not "more accurate" -- that the human-specified `dict[Any, Any]` (when one just types `dict`) isn't the actual correct type, and that the use of constant data where the value was a `str` wasn't a special case that's nonrepresentative of the more general case of what needs to be handled?

Comment: I'll note that sometimes it is useful to ask your type checker (`reveal_type` in `mypy`, for example) what it thinks is the most general type for a value before adding explicit type hints.

Comment: what is `reveal_type`? That might be the answer...

Comment: `reveal_type` used to be a typechecker extension, but now it's just a [regular function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.reveal_type) in `typing`. You can use it to ask type checker about the inferred type. Note that it may different from what LSP thinks (in general, type hints are for the type checker, and their assistance in your IDE suggestions is just a bonus for those who need it).

Comment: If you were using [Helix](https://helix-editor.com/) as your editor, the sequence to ask what type your langserver thinks something is would be space+k. I have no idea what it is in VS Code or whatever the screenshot is from.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is not focusing on one specific problem.

Comment: Sure, happy for you to close it. But I think there is not a good place on the internet to ask questions like this (Reddit is a far worse option than SO). Keen to seek SO evolve in the direction of general software development Q&A.

Comment: I think this question is valid, because the reality is implementation IS interface in much of large / legacy codebases. I've added an answer that describes how an incremental approach can mitigate the issue you are experiencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not currently possible for the type checker to tell you if your hint will worsen the LSP's understanding. Both in your example of Visual Studio Code (which uses [Pyright](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright) underneath), and [mypy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

While theoretically possible for type checkers to implement, needing this feature is a red flag. This is because your LSP should provide suggestions based on the *interface* of the function (return type), not *implementation* (function body). Otherwise, your LSP would be providing suggestions that would break when the implementation of a function you consume changes, even if its behavior remained the same!

You say:

> I'm going through an exercise of adding type hints through a large codebase

If you want to ensure your LSP retains optimal understanding of the code, you should only start adding type hints to functions that are used by other modules / packages in your code. This will get the major benefit of type hinting (establishing an interface to other team members / consumers of your service).

As for private functions, you do not need to type hint those yet. This allows you to treat their implementation as the interface, which is not a bad idea for internal code. The downside of type hinting you are experiencing (the chance of removing information from the interface accidentally) is then deferred.

Answer (score 1):

`dict` is equivalent to `dict[Any, Any]`. Type hints always override inference, so you replaced the ability to *infer* that `y['result']` has type `str` with a stated fact that `y['result']` has type `Any`.

The solution to this is inherently tool-specific, but as an example, `mypy` has an option, `--disallow-any-generic` that would flag `dict` by itself as an error. With this option, generic types have to have explicit "arguments" to indicate how the parameters are bound. If you really want `dict[Any, Any]`, you can write that, but you can't simple use `dict` as a shorthand for it.

Comment: The OP already knows this -- they state in the question that `dict[str, str]` would solve the problem.

Comment: They realized the solution, but it wasn't clear they recognized *why* it was a solution (or what exact problem it was a solution to). Also, they asked for a way to flag `dict` alone as a problem.

Comment: I agree, though, there's no way to flag an arbitrary type like `object` as "too permissive".

Comment: For clarity, yes, I understand why `dict` worsens the recommendations. The core of my issue is that when I have team members adding "type hints" in pull requests it's not obvious if the type hint they added is better or worse than what was obvious to the LSP/type checker. I would like a way to flag when a user added type hint is you know... bad.

Comment: @MYK, I don't think there's an objective enough definition of "bad" for the langserver to have any way of knowing. Yes, it's no longer suggesting string-specific results, but maybe that's _correct and intended_ behavior because a string is only one of many possible types that could be stored in that key. `disallow-any-generic` and its alternatives for other tools is really the closest you're likely to get.

Comment: ...it would be different in a language where types are determined at compile time and strictly enforced -- for those languages, yes, the compiler can make affirmatively correct assertions -- but there you'd have type assertions or type declarations, not just type hints, in the first place!

Comment: I guess my last example is the only good one to illustrate the issue (see EDIT#2), there there is a pretty good type hint that would be derived from the function code - and a less good one "tuple" that the user might add.